# The [partial] tag seems overly generic

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I was looking for a partial application tag, and found [partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/partial).

> Existing only in part; incomplete.

This seems more like a dictionary definition than a tag related to an SO topic.

Most of the questions tagged with it seem to be about templating. There's a [partials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/partials) tag that mentions templating.

Should its description be changed, or should the tag just removed entirely?

Comment: What exactly were you looking for with "partial application"? Part of an entire application? (Which, I realize now, sounds again like a literal dictionary definition.)

Comment: @RadLexus No, for partially applying a function: not giving a functions enough arguments and essentially creating a new function that takes less arguments than the original. It's really handy in functional programming.

Comment: "Partial" may used as a keyword in some programming languages to set "partial classes", "partial methods" or "partial templates". While I preferred to burninate the tag, I concerned about what way that two former related topics should be tagged into.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Should a more specific tag be created in it's place then?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto cursory glance seems to indicate that most of the recent active questions are about "partial something" rather than "partial keyword"

Comment: We already have _partial-application_, _partial-classes_, _partial-methods_ and _partial-specialization_.  _partial*s*_ seems to be Web-stack-related and might become _partial-templates_ or something; I'm not an expert there but it can probably be more descriptive.

Comment: @Jeffrey What? I swear when I typed in "partial", I couldn't see a `partial-application`.

Comment: Whoops, there is one. I wonder why it didn't show up in the suggested tags. Oh well. Thanks.

Comment: *I’m not [partial] to this tag*

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: Even in this context there is hardly any use for those tags. If you know the language, you know what partial classes are in that language. So just use language tags in this case.

Comment: Another tag that exists (though with only 20 questions) and makes sense is [tag:partial-functions]. I fully agree that [tag:partial] on its own isn't helpful.

Comment: You probably meant the tag `[parti`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'd rather just get rid of it, to be perfectly honest.

It doesn't seem like a question could be *just* tagged with it and it be on-topic, nor does it make the problem space any clearer (since people will put "partial-whatever" in their question title anyway).

Languages that have the ability to partially apply arguments in functions would be best tagged with that language, since there may be differences/discrepancies in how that works between languages.  But, my vote is firmly to remove this tag.

Answer (score 1):

[partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/partial) seems like a rather bad tag to me.

#### Tests for burnination criteria:

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   Sort of, but not in a partiularly helpful way on its own. It's incredibly ambiguous - it's used for partial classes, partial string matching, partial datasets, etc. - none of which have anything to do with each other.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   Depends, highly ambiguous. It doesn't really describe much on its own. Partial classes are no doubt on topic. [Partial wall dividers](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=partial+wall+divider&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB781GB781&oq=partial+wall+divider&aqs=chrome..69i57.1647j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) are definitely not.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   None whatsoever, as far as I can tell.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   Not at all - it's used for [partial classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48503858/independent-classes), [partial string matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48849360/is-this-correctly-done-python-partial-string-match-on-dictionary), partial datasets, [partial templates in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188158/regular-and-partial-templates), etc..

[There's 1259 questions with this tag at the time of writing.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/partial) So far as I can tell, there's [no questions that just use this tag and no others](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/204368/all-questions-with-a-single-tag), so I propose we just kill / burninate it rather than replace it with anything else.

There is a tag wiki, however this seems to be just as bad as the tag itself:

> Existing only in part; incomplete.

I assume this has just been copied [straight out the dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/partial).